# How can I set the "directory" bit in unix permissions

Tags: unix, permissions, chmod

I did a:

```
chmod 7777 MYDATA
```

On MYDATA which is a directory. Now it is no-longer recognised by unix (Cygwin actually) as a directory:

```
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 Administrators Domain Users  63 Apr  4 10:19 MYDATA
```

How can I set the first character back to being a "d"?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. That `d` isn't a permission, it's an attribute. Mostly you'll see '-' or 'd'  but you'll see a selection of others if your browse `/dev`. 
I'm actually a bit surprised you've managed to turn a directory into a file in this way. Are you entirely sure that `MYDATA` was a directory to start off with? 
Of the 4 modes you've set, you *should* have got a file (or directory!) with:

- user/group/other read/write/execute
- setgid, setuid, and 'sticky' bit set.

`chmod` shouldn't be able to turn a directory into a flat file, unless you've found a *really* strange bug.

Comment: It was definitely a directory on Friday. I need to access the considerable amount of data in folders within MYDATA. Any idea of how I might get access to them?

Comment: Actually this depends on the file system you are using to store your directories and files on (in your case maybe sth coming from Windows?).  It _should_ not be possible to change a _file_ into a _directory_ or vice versa, but if an unusual `chmod` command changed this that way, I'd call it a bug in the file system implementation, and I also would not expect to have a way back.  Besides files and directories there are also block devices, character devices, named pipes (FIFOs) and symbolic links.  None of these should be changeable into one of the others as it simply does not make sense.